# setClassLoader() Java

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclipse-plugin, classloader

I have a JavaProject with one JUnit test, and that test has this code:

```
ClassLoader sysClassLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
//Get the URLs
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader)sysClassLoader).getURLs();
for(int i=0; i< urls.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(urls[i].getFile());
}
```

and the output is:

```
/home/ubfeup/workspace/Nano/bin/
/usr/share/java/junit4-4.8.2.jar
/usr/share/java/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
/home/ubfeup/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/113/1/.cp/
/home/ubfeup/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/111/1/.cp/
/home/ubfeup/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.5.0_155965261/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/112/1/.cp/
```

But when I run my Eclipse Plugin (my plugin has JUnitCore, and runs some (not all) JUnit Tests from the project) the output is only:

```
/usr/lib/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
```

I need the Bin directory in ClassLoader, so, how can I set the URL of ClassLoader?

--
Cheers,
ZéCarlos

Comment: Is your Nano project a java only project?  And your eclipse plugin needs to understand the Nanon classpath?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the URLs used by a classloader. I really can't tell what you're trying to do here, but I suspect one of the following will help:

1) You can construct your own `URLClassLoader` with the URLs you want, and use it to load classes.

2) Eclipse offers a specific mechanism for finding resources in plugins: see, for instance [here.](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2010/07/06/reading-resources-from-plugin/)

From our discussion below, it sounds like you want to be able to use the `ClassLoader` of another plugin determined dynamically at runtime. I can't say I've ever done this specific task -- Eclipse has *extension points* which you normally use for this sort of thing -- but what I would try would be the following. You'll need the name of a class defined in the other plugin -- perhaps the developer provides this to your tool, somehow. Then you can say

```
Bundle b = Bundle.getBundle(pluginIdOfOtherPlugin);
Class c = b.loadClass(nameOfTheOneKnownClass);
ClassLoader loader = c.getClassLoader();
```

and then you can do whatever you want with `loader` (including creating your own URLClassLoader which delegates to it.)

Comment: Hi, Ernest. I don't want to load files/folders from inside of my plugin. I want to setClassLoader to point to the Bin directory of JavaProject. Like I said above, I want the "/home/ubfeup/workspace/Nano/bin/" in ClassLoader...

Comment: So you'll need to make your own URLClassLoader, giving it a file URL for that directory, and then load your classes through that ClassLoader.

Comment: And if I have a directory "/home/ubfeup/workspace/Nano/data/" with some input for JUnit Test, how can I create a URLClassLoader for that directory? (And this is a simple example, how can I find the Data directory dynamically?)

Comment: I need to run my Eclipse Plugin in the same ClassPath of Project that I execute with my Plugin. But I cannot set the ClassPath of my plugin to run in the same ClassPath! Example, my plugin is EPlugin and execute JUnit Tests on a Java Project (in workspace) XPTO, so my plugin "EPlugin" need to run in the same ClassPath of XPTO Project to get all directories that needs....

Comment: That's simple enough: make XPTO export whatever is needed in its manifest, and make XPTO a dependency of EPlugin in EPlugin's manifest. Then if you need to load even *more* classes in EPlugin, create a URLClassLoader using the new URLs, and have it delegate to EPlugin's application classloader. It seems like you're making this much harder than it actually is.

Comment: I cannot add XPTO to a dependency of EPlugin! XPTO is any JavaProject with JUnit Tests... Now I experiment my plugin executing XPTO project, but when I publish the plugin, ever user have own JavaProject with different names... I need a dynamically solution...

Answer (score 0):

If you contribute an eclipse plugin, and you want to work **with** a java project in your workspace, you need to look at [JDT Programmer's Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_int.htm).  As an eclipse plugin, the Nano classpath won't be available to your runtime plugin instance.

To get classpath information, check out [Setting the Java build path](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_classpath.htm).

It will matter how you are launching Nano?  In the same JVM or a different one?